# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory on Laravel 10.43

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm working on a laravel/docker application and having a big trouble with my database connection. I've detected the problem when trying to make an login authentication using the **Auth::attempt()** laravel method. Before this I've runned the initial laravel migrations and had no problem doing it, the migrations runned perfectly and the tables where created as expected. My scneario is:

.env database settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

database.php mysql settings:

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    container_name: "somadash1-app"
    build:
      args:
        user: laravel
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel10-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www:delegated
    networks:
      - laravelnetwork

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www:delegated
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - laravelnetwork

  # MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laravel'
        MYSQL_USER: 'laravel'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    networks:
        - laravelnetwork

networks:
  laravelnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Some other relevant things to say:

- I've tested the connection in several different ways, including directly into the mysql container, and it worked normally.
- When changing the value of **DB_HOST** variable, I get different errors:

  -For "127.0.0.1" the error is: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused, but using laravel tinker, I can see my user data normally by running the **User::find()** method.

  -For "localhost" it is: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory, same when trying to use tinker.

Been trying to solve this for two days by now, and all the possible solutions that I've found on the internet failed. I don't know what else to do, every kind of help will be welcome.

Comment: Your host within the container should be `DB_HOST=mysql` since you are using a `bridge` network

Comment: @apokryfos already tested it too. By using `DB_HOST=mysql` I don't get any error messages on my browser, but the atuthentication dosen't work as expected. And when using tinker I get this error: 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known

Comment: If you run tinker directly in the command-line it won't be able to connect to `mysql` because that hostname only exists inside the docker network (i.e. from within any of your containers). Try something like `docker compose run app php artisan tinker` to see if you can get tinker to run from inside the container

Comment: Done. I've tested tinker inside the container and it works normally, but still no success on the application... At least now I'm not recieving more of those SQL error messages related to connection, maybe my code is just wrong. I've added an edit to show my code for the login method, honestly I see nothing wrong with it. If you do so, please let me know. Thx

Comment: Does running an `Auth::attempt([ ... ])` with the credentials you are using work in tinker?

Comment: Yes, it does but I had to do some adjustments in the code to make it work... I guess that from now on will be just my old and endless fight with laravel to solve this hahaha. Anyways, your suggestions were very helpful, thanks a lot!